# Mismatch between SEQ and ACK in TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, seq, ack

I have been trying to figure out a case where a TCP connection between a HTTP client and HTTP server remains in ESTABLISHED state, lingering. This happens for 1 or 2 connections out of 1000+ connections. It is not clear if the client / server is at fault here.

I wrote a python script (using scapy) to capture all the TCP packets to figure out the root cause and I faced this specific case, where the TCP SEQ and ACK seems to be a mismatch and it is confusing me.

Here is the interesting part of the log, from the scapy script:
(after lots of packets on the same port 53332)

```
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769374665 ack:844297577 len:0
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769374665 ack:844297577 len:90
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 389255
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769374755 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769383704 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769392653 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769383704 len:0
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769401602 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769410551 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769419500 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769401602 len:0
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769428449 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769437398 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769446347 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769455296 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769464245 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769473194 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769446347 len:0
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769482143 ack:844297577 len:8949
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [PA] seq:769491092 ack:844297577 len:8949
```

... scapy script must have missed several packets here ...

```
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769750613 len:0
2019-12-21 15:54:43 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769764010 len:0
```

After a couple of hours:

```
2019-12-21 17:54:45 10.0.1.2:8080 -> 10.0.1.3:53332 [ A] seq:769764009 ack:844297577 len:0
2019-12-21 17:54:45 10.0.1.3:53332 -> 10.0.1.2:8080 [ A] seq:844297577 ack:769764010 len:0
```

At 15:54:43, the client has responded with ACK of 769764010, indicating it has received data upto 769764010. After 2 hours, the server is sending a SEQ of 769764009, which is 1 less than the ACK. And the client has continued to send the ACK of 769764010.

I am perplexed as how can SEQ be less than ACK (or how can ACK be greater than SEQ). I have verified that on both systems, the connection is still at ESTABLISHED state, so neither has sent a FIN, to have caused the increase the seq numbering.

What am I missing?

Comment: On which host are you doing the capture? If it is on the HTTP client, then it would seem to indicate that the HTTP server never received the first ACK. Packets get lost all the time. Also, just because one side is FIN (sent FIN and received ACK for it), the other side may not be FIN, so the connection is still established. Closing the connection using FIN requires a four-way handshake, and one side can be done sending, but it must still listen and ACK anything from the other side until the other side finishes closing the connection.

Comment: Captured on the server. Both are on the same LAN. Every two hours, as i realised now, both are exchanging ACKs, with the one side SEQ/ACK mismatched by 1, as specified. This, i am able to capture on both sides now. Hence reasonable sure, that no FINs have been sent by either side. Both sides, netstat is saying ESTABLISHED.

Comment: The SEQ that is 1 less is a TCP keepalive packet, and the next ACK is a response.

Comment: Agreed that it is a keepalive packet, but i dont think that should increment or affect the SEQ numbers. My question is about why there is a mismatch between SEQ and ACK

Comment: The ACK is telling the peer where it is really up to. That's what a keepalive ACK is supposed to do.

Comment: No, the problem is that peer's ACK is *one more than* the mine. I say my SEQ is 769764009 and the peer is responding with ACK of 769764010, which is one more than what the sender has sent. How is this possible?

Comment: I repeat. The ACK is telling the peer where it is really up to, which is one more than the sequence number of the keepalive, because the sequence number of the keepalive is one less than where you are really up to, because that's what a keepalive packet looks like, because that's how keepalive works. This is all documented. Look it up.

Comment: I have been dumb, sorry! And Thanks for repeating this multiple times @user207421. Ok, I got it now -- "A TCP keep-alive packet is simply an ACK with the sequence number set to one less than the current sequence number for the connection". I did not know this and this is the right answer to the question. Thanks once again!

Comment: By the way, the server is at fault. Servers should close client connections if the client appears to be dead or non-responsive. Otherwise, they are vulnerable to DoS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually @user207421 answer, but the user chose to comment, so I am writing this answer.

There was no problem in the first place. It was TCP Keepalive packets and all TCP keep-alive packets are simply an ACK with the sequence number set to one less than the current sequence number for the connection.

Hence there was really no mismatch.

Comment: Here is the TCP keep-alive specification:
<https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-101>